# Meaning of “I entered my address in"

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

Let us say that I have two physical addresses, and someone asking me which address I used to fill some document, is it correct to say : I entered my address in example-avenue, example-city.

Just wondering if this might indicate that I filled the document when I was in that location or is it clear that I am talking about the address that I used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I entered my address in example-avenue, example-city.

The appropriate preposition is *as*, as

> I filled in/ entered my address *as* ....

With this, there should be no interpretation that you were at that place.

Comment: This is correct, but James K's answer below is more idiomatic. Using "entered ... as" almost makes it sound like what you entered is not actually your correct address.

Answer (score 3):

To express this, I would use the name of the city or street as an attribute of the word "address".  Suppose I had a house in New York, and another in Los Angeles.

> I entered my New York address.

On the other hand if I had two addresses in New York, one on Beech Ave. and one on Union St.

> I entered my Beech Avenue address.